# for loop only takes last value in python aws dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to insert records into a table, but only last record(result data) from the loop is inserting into the table

Here is the code i tried:

```
CDates = ['2020-05-10','2020-05-12','2020-05-13','2020-05-16','2020-05-20']

ResultData = {}
for date in CDates:
   filterDate = Key('Date').eq(id)
   appResponse = appTable.scan(FilterExpression = filterDate)
   accResp = table.query(KeyConditionExpression = Key('PrimaryId').eq('Key'),FilterExpression = Key('Date').eq(date))
   if len(accResp['Items']) == 0:
       ResultData['PrimaryId'] = 'Key'
       ResultData['CreatedDate'] = date
       ResultData['Type'] = 'Appt'
       ResultData['Id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
       print(ResultData)
       table.put_item(Item=ResultData)
```

Not getting where did I go wrong

Comment: Do you see output from the `print()` statement more than once?

Comment: yes in print( ) I can see output more than once

Comment: you are overwiriting ResultData every time the loop runs, try assigning ResultData inside the if block

Comment: yes because the values in ResultData will change every time the loops runs(for ex: Id and CreatedDate these values will change everytime)

Comment: that __should__ still work with this though, right? unless the final inserting is happening later and only referencing the single ResultData dict

Answer (score 0):

You assigned `ResultData` outside of the loop and changed the values for the same keys every time the loop ran. Try this:

```py
CDates = ['2020-05-10', '2020-05-12', '2020-05-13', '2020-05-16', '2020-05-20']

for date in CDates:
    filterDate = Key('Date').eq(id)
    appResponse = appTable.scan(FilterExpression=filterDate)
    accResp = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('PrimaryId').eq('Key'),
        FilterExpression=Key('Date').eq(date))
    if len(accResp['Items']) == 0:
        ResultData = {
            'PrimaryId': 'Key',
            'CreationDate': date,
            'Type': 'Appt',
            'Id': str(uuid.uuid4())
        }
        print(ResultData)
        table.put_item(Item=ResultData)
```

Comment: I tried ur code but the result is same it's inserting only one value to the table

Comment: @Harry what do you get when you change the last line to `print(table.put_item(Item=ResultData))`

Comment: @Harry you only get one response?

Comment: No multiple I just copied only one response

Comment: Hmm, a response code 200 would seem to indicate a successful operation

Comment: Exactly, but it inserts a single record only

Comment: are the `Id`s returned from `print(ResultData)` all unique?

Comment: does `'PrimaryId'` have to be unique in the table? Because they are all set to 'Key' here

Comment: it can be the same no issue